# Color of listview item is very faint

Tags: android, android-listview

Sorry if i am repeating the question.

I am reading SMS/s from inbox and showing them in the listview.

I can see the SMS/s in the listview as listview item after execution.

Only problem is that, the text color of listview item is vary pale.(text i am getting is not readable/visible).

I tried to change it, but nothing happened.

How i can change this color to black or to any other color ?

Here is my **activity_view_task.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_tasks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Tasks"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_view_task"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_tasks"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
    android:textColor="#000000">

</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my java file from where I am adding the items to the listview :**

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewTask extends Activity {

TextView tv_view_task;
ListView lv_view_task;
static String sms = "";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_task);
    tv_view_task=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_view_task);
    lv_view_task=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_view_task);

    List<String> msgList = getSms();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, msgList); 
      lv_view_task.setAdapter(adapter); 
}


public List<String> getSms() {
    List<String> labeles = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);


    // Read the sms data and store it in the list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
            String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
            sms = "From : " + address + " : " + body;
            labeles.add(sms);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();

    return labeles;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_view_task, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**After executing it looks like this :**

[image]

Comment: Don't want to custom layout for ListView?

Comment: Can you post any example or link for custom layout for listview ?

Comment: You don't need to have a custom adapter in your case, see the @ManishPatel's answer. You just have to change the item layout in the adapter and create it with a TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to **create a custom layout** for your ListView items where you set your desired textcolor.

In this way, you do not even need a **custom-adapter**.

e.g. custom_textview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, you can use your layout with the **ArrayAdapter**:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_textview, aa);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Custom layout name **row_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UselessParent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Make Custom Adapter globally like:

```
MyAdapter adp;
```

now initialize it on onCreate() method:

```
adp = new MyAdapter (YourActivity.this, yourArrayList);


class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context c;
    String[] yourarraylist;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context fullImage, String[] yourarraylist) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = fullImage;
        this.yourarraylist= yourarraylist;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return yourarraylist.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent,
                    false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            // set text here
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity_view_task.xml:

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```