# Prompt in spinner is displaying with white text

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my App there is a spinner, the selected item of spinner is white in color.

And my app background is also white. so I can not see the text which is displaying on spinner(at 0 location)

How can I change the text color of spinner. I am more thanks full if you also tell me how to change the border color of a spinner. Spinner is displaying bright in white background.

My code:

```
        CustomAdapter1<String> arrayAdapter1 = new CustomAdapter1<String>(IRCMSActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, divisions, 0);
    arrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.spinner_button);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
```

Custom Adapter class:

```
class CustomAdapter1<T> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public CustomAdapter1(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] symboles, int value) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, symboles);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent,
            int value) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);          
            textView.setText(divisions[position]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I can see the text in black color(rounded with red color) in emulator but in tablet the text moving to white color. I donno my it is happening. Unable to take screen shot in tab, so posting emulator screen shot. 
Please help.
[image]

Comment: Go to my this answer:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760442/color-of-listview-item-is-very-faint/20760531#20760531](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760442/color-of-listview-item-is-very-faint/20760531#20760531)

Comment: you can use Custom layout for that. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760442/color-of-listview-item-is-very-faint/20760531#20760531

Comment: @MD tried getting the same result. I donno why.:(

Comment: Post your all code and snap for better understanding

Comment: Posted please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use the :

```
Spinner st = new Spinner(this);
st.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fffffff0")); //Just put the color code get the color of the spinner Changed
```